# How to prevent items to be changed by mouse wheel on comboxbox when it's in readonly in silverlight without disabling control

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

In my code I have this

```
<ComboBox Width="Auto"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Libelle}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <bh:IsReadOnlyBehavior
            IsReadOnly="{Binding Item.IsReadOnly, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ComboBox>
```

The IsReadOnlyBehavior set the comboxbox on readonly state when needed.
But when the combobox is in readonly state, I can change value whith scrolling with my mouse.
Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: You can have a look on this "similar" post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882993/c-sharp-how-do-i-prevent-mousewheel-scrolling-in-my-combobox

Comment: In what context do you need to have a readonly ComboBox? (ComboBox is an input control after all.) I ask this question not without reason, the "readonly approach" bears a certain scent. The DataGrid for example has an inbuilt mechanism for readonly cells.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`IsHitVisible="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) property value to make the Combobox suppress events.

Comment: This works but the control content can't be selected to be copied. I need control content be selectable for copy/paste purpose.

Comment: @ToyiKADJINA This will make the combobox completely disabled, you should edit your question then