# Editable Combobox disable mouse scroling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Here is my code

```
<ComboBox MaxDropDownHeight="100" 
IsEditable="True" 
SelectedValue="{Binding Cate.Id, Mode=OneWay}" 
SelectedItem="{BindingCate,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
SelectedValuePath="Id" 
ItemsSource="{Binding CateCollection}" 
IsTextSearchEnabled="False"/>
```

I need to disable scrolling on editable mode for `ComboBox`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - how do I prevent mousewheel-scrolling in my combobox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882993/c-sharp-how-do-i-prevent-mousewheel-scrolling-in-my-combobox)