# Prevent scrolling in comboboxes (mouse over)

Tags: winforms, combobox, mouseevent, mousewheel

I would like to prevent scrolling in comboboxes when the mouse is over the combobox (mouse over). I have already tried the following solution, but it only stops scrolling in the combobox when it is expanded.

[C# - how do I prevent mousewheel-scrolling in my combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882993/c-sharp-how-do-i-prevent-mousewheel-scrolling-in-my-combobox)

Comment: What is the type of your project? The linked project is wpf, but you use the winforms tag here.

Comment: It's a plain Windows Forms App but the answer is also working for UserControls in Winfroms (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883072/5586390)

Comment: I tested it, and it works(combobox is not expanded). What is the `UserControls` in your comment?

Comment: Did you add the event handler? It's not listed in the PropertyGrid (it's set to `[Browsable(false)]`). You have to add it manually, in the Constructor of the Parent's Form (or whatever other Window is hosting it). Can you show what you did?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to extend the `ComboBox` control, and surppress the MouseWheel message.

Something like this:

```
public class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
    {
        if (m.Msg == 522 /* WM_MOUSEWHEEL */) 
        {
            return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void Combo_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
            if (!cmb.DroppedDown)
            {
                ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
                //this.Focus();
            }
        }
```